# What is the average lifespan of most maple trees?

Tags: trees, maple, lifespan

In general how long do maple trees live?  Does the lifespan vary a lot according to species?  I'm thinking of planting a few in my yard and I'm wondering how long they will be around.

Comment: There was a big maple in the yard where I grew up and now it's bigger still.  So I'd say at least 50 years.  I'm sure someone will have a real answer.  Keeping them properly trimmed is important if you live in an area with heavy snowfall.

Comment: Lifespan will vary by species. Silver maple is more fragile, for one. There are some massive sugar(?) maples in my town that are probably 100 years old -- one fell down on our driveway last year and according to the rings was ~110 years old. They're likely to outlive you!

Comment: Depends on the environment and the species.  Sugar maples do not tolerate salt or traffic/exhaust.  But they do live a long time in the right environment.  I would also caution AGAINST planting Norway maple - which is an invasive/nuisance species.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that affect lifespan for all trees:

- If you live in an old growth forest that has never been logged larger maples can live well over 200 years.
- If you live in an urban environment in USDA zones 3 to 7

  - Norway maple 100 years  (Invasive in some areas and does not play well with others)
  - Red maple    100 years
  - Silver maple 100 years  (I cannot imagine why you would want to plant this species)
  - Sugar maple  75 years (away from compacted soil)
- If you live where the [Asian long horned beetle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_long-horned_beetle) has been seen then the lifespan of a maple could be very short.

There are [many kinds of maples](http://www.maple-trees.com/) that are smaller such as the Amur Maple. I'm sure there's something that will fit.  My choice of species would not include Ash or Maple due the possible appearance of [introduced pests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_ash_borer) such as the Emerald Ash Borer or the Asian Long Horned Beetle in your region.  If you have the room [Gingko Biloba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gingko_biloba) seems immune to almost every pest and disease.

Comment: what is wrong with silver maple?

Comment: @Tim: Silver maple has an aggressive root system and relatively soft wood and weak branch structure. This makes it prone to damage in high winds or heavy snow/ice. It doesn't make much sense to plant it when there are so many better choices.

Comment: I would agree that the silver maple is bothersome in urban areas, but I wouln't call it useless...it does grow very fast and I think it has a prettier leaf structure than red maple.  Although I would go with a red/silver hybrid (Freeman maple) if I wanted to combine the fast growth of the silver and the sturdiness of the red.

Comment: Silver Maples in urban areas are trouble. Their roots seek water and infiltrate water pipes. They have a poor branch structure that unusual weather can cause broken branches or splits in branches. With so many good cultivars I think the best place for the species Silver Maple is a botanical garden or rural area.

Comment: Silver maples can be tapped for maple syrup.  So can red - but norways are pretty useless.  I guess I was just quetsioning why the negative comment on silvers but norways are far worse as a species

Comment: Some hybrids between silver and red maples have foliage like silver maple, but structure and habit of the red. They will grow in sweet soil where most reds won't.

Comment: @Tim, norway maples have superior shade. In my area, they are valued landscape trees, and can sell for $30 apiece, if they are good 7' three year olds. The purple variety is more popular here.





4,4821119
add comment

Comment: @jmusser - that is unfortunate - they are invasive and terrible for landscaping.  They provide decent shade but at a huge price and drive away native species and ruin the turf

Comment: @Tim, in my area, they are not invasive, and have nice habits. They need care and don't go wild. Why do you say they ruin the turf? Silver maples are worse in my area because they drop sticks everywhere. I wonder why they are different in your area.

Comment: @jmusser  This article  http://ontariotrees.com/mondaygarden/article.php?id=133 on Norway Maples show how opinions have changed about this tree.  From valued hardwood to major pest in only thirty years.

Comment: @jmusser - they have a shallow and dense root structure that chokes off all other vegetation.  They are not desirable.  On Long Island the Norways have taken over as a dominant tree/species.  They may provide shade, but they do so at a huge cost to diversity.

Comment: Then why does grass grow so well under them?

Comment: You all are giving the silver maple a bad rap. It's a myth that their roots infiltrate water pipes; any tree will if there is a break that is leaking moisture. I have a beautiful silver maple on my parkway that has NEVER had storm damage in the 17 years I've lived in my house. I don't know the age, it was fairly large when I moved in, but has just gotten more beautiful as the years have gone on. I guess it's a happy tree. Located in Oak Park IL (Chicago), heavy clay soil, planted on parkway.

Comment: I have 7 mature silver maples in my yard. While I wouldn't add any (especially near a septic), the existing ones have not caused any of the issues, aside from the fact they drop a tremendous amount of seeds & "fruit"....and a few fallen branches after a storm Saint Charles, IL